# I also made a Twitter account that polls the Meta RSS feed

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, twitter

For those of us who follow the meta site too!

You can find it [here](http://twitter.com/androidsemeta).  It will only post one tweet per hour of the newest questions.

Again, If anyone would like to make a better Twitter icon, please do.

Whenever we get an official domain name, the twitter name can change accordingly.

Comment: Maybe this could be merged with the other "question"?